# Determine the directions in which the directional derivative of the function $f(x,y)=x^2+\sin(xy)$ has value $1$ at the point $(1,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Determine the directions in which the directional derivative of the function
>   $f(x,y)=x^2+\sin(xy)$ has value $1$ at the point $(1,0)$

I know the definition of directional derivative. My work is:

$$\nabla f(x,y) = \langle 2x+y\cos(xy), x\cos(xy)\rangle$$  $$\nabla f(0,2) = \langle2,1\rangle$$
get $u=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.

$$D_v f(x,y)=\nabla f\cdot u$$ $$\nabla f\cdot u=1$$
$$2\cos\theta+\sin\theta=1$$

How can I get the vector $u$ from here?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for all vectors $(a,b)$ who are such that $<\nabla f(1,0),(a,b)>=1.$ Observe that $$\nabla f(1,0)=(2x+y\cos(xy),x\cos(xy))|_{(1,0)}=(2,1).$$ Then you have to find what $a$ and $b$ verify $2a+b=1,$ and finally the answer is $$S=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,;\,b=1-2a\}=(0,1)+\mathrm{span(1,-2)}.$$

Comment: thanks,, but i dont understand the final,,, why,, and what do you say that $span$

Comment: It is just a notation to simplify the writing of $S.$ If you are given $v_1,...,v_n$ vectors, then $\mathrm{span}(v_1,...,v_n)$ is the set of all linear cominations of your $v_i.$